# Combinatoric problem in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinatorics

I am new to functional programming. Just now I solved my first "real world" task using Haskell and now I'm wondering whether I got it "right" and what can be improved.

The problem arises from tensor calculations (I am a theoretical physicist), where I have the tensor product of \$\frac{n}{2}\$ identical symmetric tensors and I am looking for all indistinguishable distributions of \$n\$ indices, i.e. terms like \$\eta^{a c} \eta^{b e} \eta^{d f}\$.

The combinatorics is easy, there are \$(n-1)\times(n-3)\times\dots\times1\$ different terms and prescriptions to enlist them all are easy to conceive.

I implemented the following algorithm:

**input**: string of even length ("indices")

**output**: rose tree representing all permutations as described above, a node is a pair (my implementation: two-element list) of indices, each branch from root node to leaf is one permutation

**recursive construction**:
From string of length \$n\$ (example: `"abcdef"`), construct \$n-1\$ nodes and "remainders", where the first index of each node is the first index of the input string (example: `[("ab", "cdef"), ("ac", "bdef"), ("ad", "bcef"), ("ae", "bcdf"), ("af", "bcde")]`). Repeat with all "remainders".

Now this is my implementation in Haskell:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Tree

--- given string of n indices a:is,
--- construct all (n-1) two-character
--- strings a:i:[] and the reduced
--- string of (n-2) remaining indices
--- undefined if n == 1
innerEtas :: String -> [(String, String)]
innerEtas (x:[]) = undefined
innerEtas (x:xs) = map (\a -> ([x, a], filter (/=a) xs)) xs
innerEtas [] = []

--- build up tree by recursive application
--- of innerEtas
buildEtas :: String -> Forest String 
buildEtas [] = []
buildEtas xs = let ys = innerEtas xs
               in map (\(node, list) -> Node node $ buildEtas list) ys

--- flatten Tree to list of strings
treeToStrings :: Tree String -> [String]
treeToStrings (Node n []) = [n]
treeToStrings (Node n ts) = liftA2 (++) [n] (forestToStrings ts)

forestToStrings :: Forest String -> [String]
forestToStrings ts = concat $ map treeToStrings ts

--- build ansatz tree from n indices
ansatzEtas :: Integer -> Forest String
ansatzEtas n
  | n < 0 = undefined
  | n `mod` 2 /= 0 = undefined
  | otherwise = buildEtas $ take (fromIntegral n) ['a'..'z']

main = do
        putStrLn $ drawForest $ ansatzEtas 8
        print $ forestToStrings $ ansatzEtas 8
        print $ (forestToStrings $ ansatzEtas 26) !! 10000
```

I am really impressed by Haskells lazy evaluation, which in the last line allows me to obtain certain combinations of `['a'..'z']` without first calculating them all! So I believe I got this aspect right.

So my question is, did I make any style errors? Did I miss idioms of functional programming and Haskell which would make the code better in some ways? Are there issues with space or time?

Comment: I don't understand what you are counting. What is an "undistinguishable distribution of n indices" exactly?

Comment: I guess it's enumerating *sets of (n/2) disjoint pairs* you can make out of n elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is purely combinatorial: it doesn't depend on the actual values of the elements. That can be made explicit by using more general types. Compare these signatures:

```
ansatzEtas :: Integer -> Forest String
ansatzEtas :: Integer -> [a] -> Forest (a, a)
-- takes the alphabet as a parameter (length must be >= the first argument n)
```

- The output is guaranteed to be a forest of pairs.
- Now that `a` is a type parameter, we are guaranteed that the pairs contain only elements from the original list.

---

We can easily get back a forest of strings using the fact that trees are functors:

```
pairToList :: Forest (a, a) -> Forest [a]
pairToList = (fmap . fmap) (\(x, y) -> [x, y])
```

---

More precise types make mistakes much less likely, and can even help us know what to write. For example, imagine we're still trying to write `innerEtas`, and we want to know what to put in place of the underscore:

```
innerEtas :: String -> [(String, String)]
innerEtas (x:xs) = map (\a -> (_, filter (/=a) xs)) xs
```

We can try to compile this code as it is, with the underscore, and GHC will report that this hole is of expected type String.

```
• Found hole: _ :: String
```

It also helpfully tells us that `xs :: [Char]` is in scope. On a tired day, one might then mistakenly interpret that as advice to put `xs` in:

```
innerEtas (x:xs) = map (\a -> (xs, filter (/=a) xs)) xs
                               -- Bug!
```

Looking back, before we even start writing `innerEtas`, we know that it's supposed to give us pairs, and we can say it in the type.

```
innerEtas :: [a] -> [((a, a), [a])]
innerEtas (x:xs) = map (\a -> (_, filter (/=a) xs)) xs
```

Here we would be told the following expected type:

```
• Found hole: _ :: (a, a)
```

Which is hopefully much more helpful to determine what goes where.

---

This generalization may introduce a bit of a challenge, because `innerEtas` uses `(/=)`, which requires an `Eq` constraint. Two options:

- Just add the `Eq a` constraint everywhere, this is an easy solution, we still get most of the benefits of the generalization anyway.
- Rewrite `innerEtas` to not use `(/=)`, instead write a custom recursive function or use other combinators than `filter`. This can help avoid mistakes when making heavy use of `Eq`, but arguably this is not the case here.

Still, in this case there's a cute one-liner to extract an element from a list and keep the rest, nondeterministically, without using `Eq`:

```
pick :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pick xs = [(y, ys ++ ys') | (ys, y : ys') <- liftA2 zip inits tails xs]
-- inits, tails from Data.List

-- Example
pick [1,2,3] = [(1,[2,3]),(2,[1,3]),(3,[1,2])]
```

---

Some refactoring is possible between `innerEtas` and `buildEtas`. There is redundancy because both are checking whether the list is empty. In fact, `x` is quite a bit more special than the other elements, and we can take it apart in `buildEtas` already. Then `innerEtas` could take `x` separately from the tail as an argument, but it becomes a one-liner that we might as well inline:

```
buildEtas :: [a] -> Forest (a, a)
buildEtas [] = []
buildEtas (x : []) = undefined   -- I think this is unnecessary, but kept it to remain close to the original code
buildEtas (x : xs) = let ys = map (\(y, zs) -> ((x, y), zs) (pick xs)
                     in map (\(node, list) -> Node node $ buildEtas list) ys
```